# Is OpenVpn community a VPN-host ? Or just a protocol?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Im trying to understand what openvpn really is, but its confusing to me.

1 - Openvpn is the same as openvpn community ?

2- Is openVpn a free opensource tool to host a Vpn server ?

3 - OpenVpn has a free vpn server to provide vpn service for free ?

4 - openvpn requires a configuration file ovpn, that can be download from any other vpn provider, such as nordvpn. Does it means that, for ex, Nordvpn is the host server that will be providing the vpn service, and the openvpn was just the tool/protocol to connect to the nordvpn server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenVPN](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwig7o_IpPD1AhUyheAKHQboD7sQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fopenvpn.net%2F&usg=AOvVaw0o3SuyhGHGgacxNlyQzwN-) is a free and opensource virtual private network system that allows you to create point-to-point or site-to-site connections to remote facilities or systems.

To answer your questions -

> OpenVPN vs OpenVPN community

I am not sure what exactly is being asked. When I was looking I did not find anything that mentions an OpenVPN community option.

> Is openVpn a free opensource tool to host a Vpn server ?

Yes. OpenVPN is free and open source. It was developed and distributed under the [GPL2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html). It does allow users to install and configure both a VPN server and a VPN client used to connect to other VPN servers.

> OpenVpn has a free vpn server to provide vpn service for free ?

Sort of. It is free and it can provide VPN services for free. But you will still need to setup and configure the OpenVPN server for clients to connect with. If you are wondering if OpenVPN just sets up a free VPN to protect your activity then no. You should look at other VPN providers. Unless you decided to host your own OpenVPN server on some cloud provider.

> openvpn requires a configuration file ovpn, that can be download from any other vpn provider, such as nordvpn. Does it means that, for ex, Nordvpn is the host server that will be providing the vpn service, and the openvpn was just the tool/protocol to connect to the nordvpn server ?

Yes. OpenVPN can utilize configuration files from other 3rd party VPN providers like [Nord](https://support.nordvpn.com/General-info/1047408082/What-is-OpenVPN.htm), [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/helpdesk/kb/articles/where-can-i-find-your-ovpn-files), [Express](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUhZu7pPD1AhXLUt8KHaUbAd8QFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.expressvpn.com%2Fsupport%2Fvpn-setup%2Fmanual-config-for-windows-xp-vista-7-8-with-openvpn%2F&usg=AOvVaw3QuOMpgCVdCFN1t6L9FCrs) etc. Essentially these companies host their own OpenVPN servers, or something similar and then provide you (their customers) with OpenVPN configs to connect to their VPN network. OpenVPN is not a protocol unto itself but as you stated a client.

Comment: OpenVPN inherently implements is own VPN protocol. Nothing forbids you to create your own implementation compartible with it, for example, Mikrotik did it that way (though their implementation inside RrouterOS is barely usable)

Comment: That is a fair point. That being said I am not sure that is within the scope of what `user1563977` was asking.